# Azure Spot VM average up time

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine, preemptive

I am trying to evaluate whether I should use Spot VMs and the measure for availability is given as a percentage by Azure.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/viewing-eviction-rates-spot-virtual-machines-azure-portal-dave-callan/

Does anyone know where I can find the average time a VM is available?

Optimally I would like to have a Bell curve to estimate the probability of my jobs finishing.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure spot VMs are mostly used when your workload can handle sudden interruptions without damaging the process too much.

When it comes to the **percentage**, the formula looks like this:

```
(total_evictions * time_lost) / total_runtime = eviction rate
```

So for example, let's say that you want to run a VM for 100 hours, and the eviction rate is 5%, the number of evictions is hard to tell, but could be something like the following examples:

```
// 50 evictions, each removed 0.1h of computation time.
(50 * 0.1) / 100 = 0.05 = 5% 

// 10 evictions, each removed 1h of computation time.    
(10 * 1) / 100 = 0.10 = 10% 

// 2 evictions, each removed 5h of computation time.    
(2 * 5) / 100 = 0.10 = 10%
```

So there is no exact answer to your question, and also no average, only speculation, and mathematics :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

For the last two examples, the answer should be 10% though.

I would still be interested about the actual Up time. 
I believe companies like [Spot](https://spot.io/resources/azure-pricing/what-are-azure-spot-virtual-machines/) must have information about the runtime from the customers that they support.

Comment: Haha, guess I was thinking a little to fast. They sure do, and I agree that it would be intresting to see the stats.